# Stuck at the "You died" screen after being killed by an invader

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm really not sure what to put it down to, because of the isolated incident it occurred in, so I thought I would see what anyone else can com up with.

I was in the Belfrey Luna, going to fight the boss, when a member of the Bell Keeper Covenant invaded. He looked pretty suspicious, enough so that I immediately knew the outcome was going to be bad. Dual-wielding Heide Swords, A crown and no chest armour.

The fight went as expected: I lost horribly, but that's when the glitch(?) occurred. After I died, the screen faded, the sound played, but he was never banished and I was stuck staring at a grey-scale screen and the "YOU DIED" never showed. This happened 3 times in about half an hour (same guy invaded 3 times) until I finally gave in and went elsewhere. I was forced to restart the game each time.

So what do people think? Glitch? Hack? Or a really bad lag spike?

Comment: It's not lag that a guarantee

Comment: @Ramhound what makes you think that?

Comment: Because lag is slang for latency and what you describe isn't latency

Comment: How long did you wait before restarting? I have lost to an invader before and had to sit for several minuets while the game figured out how to send him home and respawn me.

Comment: I gave u after about a minute I'd say. But this really was just for the one invader. I have been invaded by other players before, and two others in that area (Belfry Luna) and It was only that one player that caused the 'incident'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a glitch/server error, the server doesnt always catch the multiplayer match being over so it will be stuck in that stage. So yeah either wait a long time or just restart. They are working on fixing this error so dont worry

Comment: Do you have a source for any of this or just personal speculation?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it may seem like an extraordinarily long time, but in some situations this is normal. In cases like the Dragon Covenant, after getting the "Target Defeated" message, they also get an item (Dragon Scale), keeping them in your world a bit longer than usual.